# Client-side Object Model Load Test Metrics

Tags: 2010, document-library, client-object-model, performance, load-testing

I would like to know if anyone has done any load testing on using managed .NET Client Side Object Model (CSOM)?

I am mainly looking for metrics (graphs, spreadsheets, etc.) on the following:

- Large document libraries

  The effects of large number of clients trying to query document libraries with large number of documents.
- Document libraries with large files

  The effects of large number of clients trying to download these large files simultaneously

I would like to get an idea on the threshold limits. I know this depends on a lot of factors, for example network speed, etc. But, I would like to get a general idea so I can handle these limits better my code.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this technet article showing the limits and boundaries of SP 2010. It might be helpful when you try to plan your SP solution.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

But there is no mention of CSOM :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Microsoft is yet to release any documents/case study which focuses on the performance of the Client Object Model. I have searched extensively for it and the closest thing I found is how to increase efficiency of queries for the Client Object Model:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx